# rlang not updating to latest in Databricks

Tags: r, databricks, devtools, rlang, install.packages

I want to install a few packages that require the `rlang` package.

However, when I install the latest, it doesn't actually update in databricks. Here are the options I did where none of them worked. Does anyone know a different option to update the `rlang` package?

`tidyr` and `slackr` won't install because `rlang` package isn't updated

I tried everything up to this point and no luck with updating rlang to the latest package in Databricks.

Option1:

```
remove.packages('rlang')
install.packages('rlang')
sessionInfo()
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.4.6       compiler_3.6.3     prettyunits_1.1.1  TeachingDemos_2.10
 [5] remotes_2.1.1      tools_3.6.3        testthat_2.3.2     digest_0.6.25     
 [9] pkgbuild_1.1.0     pkgload_1.1.0      tibble_3.0.3       memoise_1.1.0     
[13] lifecycle_0.2.0    gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.7       
[17] cli_2.0.2          stringr_1.4.0      withr_2.2.0        hwriter_1.3.2     
[21] vctrs_0.3.6        desc_1.2.0         fs_1.4.2           rprojroot_1.3-2   
[25] grid_3.6.3         glue_1.4.1         R6_2.4.1           processx_3.4.3    
[29] fansi_0.4.1        sessioninfo_1.1.1  purrr_0.3.4        callr_3.4.3       
[33] SparkR_3.0.0       magrittr_1.5       backports_1.1.8    ps_1.3.3          
[37] hwriterPlus_1.0-3  ellipsis_0.3.1     htmltools_0.5.0    assertthat_0.2.1  
[41] Rserve_1.8-7       colorspace_1.4-1   stringi_1.4.6      munsell_0.5.0     
[45] crayon_1.3.4
```

Option 2:

```
remove.packages('rlang')
library(devtools)
install_version("rlang", "0.4.9")
sessionInfo()
 [1] pillar_1.4.6       compiler_3.6.3     prettyunits_1.1.1  TeachingDemos_2.10
 [5] remotes_2.1.1      tools_3.6.3        testthat_2.3.2     digest_0.6.25     
 [9] pkgbuild_1.1.0     pkgload_1.1.0      tibble_3.0.3       memoise_1.1.0     
[13] lifecycle_0.2.0    gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.7       
[17] cli_2.0.2          stringr_1.4.0      withr_2.2.0        hwriter_1.3.2     
[21] vctrs_0.3.6        desc_1.2.0         fs_1.4.2           rprojroot_1.3-2   
[25] grid_3.6.3         glue_1.4.1         R6_2.4.1           processx_3.4.3    
[29] fansi_0.4.1        sessioninfo_1.1.1  purrr_0.3.4        callr_3.4.3       
[33] SparkR_3.0.0       magrittr_1.5       backports_1.1.8    ps_1.3.3          
[37] hwriterPlus_1.0-3  ellipsis_0.3.1     htmltools_0.5.0    assertthat_0.2.1  
[41] Rserve_1.8-7       colorspace_1.4-1   stringi_1.4.6      munsell_0.5.0     
[45] crayon_1.3.4
```

When I try to run `install.packages('tidyr')` this is the error message when I try above:
`library('tidyr')`

```
Error : package or namespace load failed for 'tidyr' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
versionCheck = vI[[i]]): Error : package or namespace load failed for 'tidyr' in loadNamespace(i, 
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace 'rlang' 0.4.7 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required
```

Comment: Are you loading any packages before you run these commands? Do you have any commands in your `.Rprofile` that would do that? That seems like a lot of packages to show up in your sessionInfo at start. it's unclear what's loading them all. That should not happen with a clear R restart.

Comment: Figured out that I need to download the package directly into the cluster. You are probably right that it got loaded from another package previously

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the package into the cluster (outside of the notebook) to have rlang work.